# Customize HAProxy retry-on

Tags: haproxy

According to the HAProxy [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4-retry-on), the only HTTP codes that are acceptable as keywords after `retry-on` are `404`, `408`, `425`, `500`, `503` and `504`.

I'd like to retry on `421`s; I haven't been able to find docs on creating custom keywords for `retry-on`, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

Long answer: You can see in the code that only the documented Codes are implemented.
[proxy_parse_retry_on](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/02fd3caa8f042a95418fcc27ac080415eb00d0f5/src/proxy.c#L823)